# Using StringFormat.SetTabStops(), is it possible to align tabs?

Tags: c#, .net, string-formatting, tabstop

I'd like to be able to align the tabstops I use in a `StringFormat` (set with the `SetTabStops()` method)

Is this possible?

Comment: Some tabbing systems allow you to align a tabstop, left/right/central. for example... http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:gn3m_Q1whg_u_M:http://www.geekgirls.com/images/ruler02.jpg&t=1

Comment: (left, right or near, far if you follow the `StringAlignment` model.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See (Update: Didn't help much as per comments below)

- [Is there an easy way to create two columns in a popup text window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72198/is-there-an-easy-way-to-create-two-columns-in-a-popup-text-window)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.stringformat.settabstops.aspx
- http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharpAPI/System.Drawing/StringFormatSetTabStops.htm
- http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=318601

---

Or, as I commented further and recommend by yourself :)

*In String.Format I don't think so as all it specializes in is replacing {n} parts with different formatters. One thing you may be able to do is to split the string by '\t', and apply .PadLeft() or .PadRight() to each and then string.Join() them, or use any of the suggestions above, but, string.Format is likely dead end for this one.*

Comment: Please forgive me, I already know how to use `SetTabStops` to setup basic near aligned tabs, I am wondering if there is an in-built mechanism for aligning a tab centrally or far, as well as near.

Comment: In String.Format I don't think so as all it specializes in is replacing {n} parts with different formatters. One thing you may be able to do is to split the string by '\t', and apply .PadLeft() or .PadRight() to each and then string.Join() them, or use any of the suggestions above, but, string.Format is likely dead end for this one.

Comment: Make ^ this your answer, and you get a shiny up-vote and a green check.